# Access Linked Tables, how to force relational values

Tags: ms-access, relational-database, linked-tables

[image: Relationships]

Hopefully the image above makes it thru. So the way this works is that a user uses a form to enter the values on the Vuln_Remediation_Planning table. After all vulnerabilities associated with a patchID and existing OS have been entered, he moves to the next form where he is suppose to mitigate the risk associated with the vulnerabilities, and you can have multiple mitigating measures which is why the table is separate.

**My question:**
Right now when using the compensation form, the user has to select each patchID, OS, and vulnerability ID for each mitigating measure they select... this is cumbersome and error prone. Recall the first form only operates on the planning table, the second form operates on the compensation table.. but they are related so I feel the user would want to use a single drop down to select the top the primary keys, already assign in the previous table.

I was going to ask how to handle this, but I may have solved my own problem... 3 column combo box right, with the row source coming from the Remediation planning.... lol what do you think, any other ideas?

Comment: Are there many PatchID, OS combination.  Is there merit putting some form of date picker to further limit?

Comment: Not sure what the date picker will do. Yes there are many. The PatchID is actually a publication ID... so for example Cisco releases a security notice (patchID/PublicationID) saying 20 OSs (OS field) are each affected my many different vulnerabilities (vulnerabilityID field). So there could be a lot. For each OS/vulnerability pair associated with a publication, at least one but possibly more mitigating measures must be selected. FYI... the combo box idea will not work, only 1 column can be bound apparently... I'm stuck again.

Comment: I was more thinking along the lines of limiting, i.e. start date = date()-14 or the like.  What about a subform?  Then you just set the parent <> child links.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. On the compensation table I just created a continuous form, and moved the OS and patchID fields to the header. When opening the form normally, it looks funny because the header values change when records are selected (as would be expected if they were all on the same row). Then from the remediation planning form, I have a button to open the compensating measures form that filters it so only the patchID/OS of the parent for is shown. Additionally, in the open event of the compensating measures form, I set the default values of PATCHID/OS using open args (in case no records are there yet or the user adds new records... otherwise it opens blank when there are no records.